# how to show Promo code or coupon code on Checkout page in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon-codes, checkout-page

How can i show Promo code or coupon code on Checkout page in magento 1.9. And we can have option in admin panel or we do by code? please help me!!!

Comment: on which step you want to call coupon code form ?

Comment: On right side of checkout page or in payment information on chechkout page.

Comment: @Pawan: I want to add coupon code in order review step in checkout page, can you help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call coupon code at checkout by following code:

```
<div class="custom-coupan">
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_coupon')
->setTemplate('checkout/cart/coupon.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
</div>
```

You need to add code at:

> mag1Root/app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/checkout/onepage/progress.phtml

**Note:** when you apply coupon code it will redirect to cart page, So need a proper overriding of controller and redirect from where from is submitted.

**Update I**

If we need to show success/error message on checkout page, we need to create a module say `Mago_Coupon`

Create

> app/etc/modules/Mago_Coupon.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mago_Coupon>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Checkout />
            </depends>
        </Mago_Coupon>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Mago/Coupon/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mago_Coupon>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mago_Coupon>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
   <routers>
        <coupon>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>Mago_Coupon</module>
                 <frontName>coupon</frontName>
             </args>         
        </coupon>
        <checkout>
            <args>
                 <modules>
                     <Mago_Coupon before="Mage_Checkout">Mago_Coupon</Mago_Coupon>
                 </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Mago/Coupon/controllers/CartController.php

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Checkout') . DS . 'CartController.php';
class Mago_Coupon_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
    public function couponPostAction()
    {

        /**
         * No reason continue with empty shopping cart
         */
        if (!$this->_getCart()->getQuote()->getItemsCount()) {

            $this->_redirectReferer();
            return;
        }

        $couponCode = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('coupon_code');
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('remove') == 1) {
            $couponCode = '';
        }
        $oldCouponCode = $this->_getQuote()->getCouponCode();

        if (!strlen($couponCode) && !strlen($oldCouponCode)) {
            $this->_redirectReferer();
            return;
        }

        try {
            $codeLength = strlen($couponCode);
            $isCodeLengthValid = $codeLength && $codeLength <= Mage_Checkout_Helper_Cart::COUPON_CODE_MAX_LENGTH;

            $this->_getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
            $this->_getQuote()->setCouponCode($isCodeLengthValid ? $couponCode : '')
                ->collectTotals()
                ->save();

            if ($codeLength) {
                if ($isCodeLengthValid && $couponCode == $this->_getQuote()->getCouponCode()) {
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(
                        $this->__('Coupon code "%s" was applied.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($couponCode))
                    );
                    $this->_getSession()->setCartCouponCode($couponCode);
                } else {
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__('Coupon code "%s" is not valid.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($couponCode))
                    );
                }
            } else {
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($this->__('Coupon code was canceled.'));
            }

        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Cannot apply the coupon code.'));
            Mage::logException($e);
        }

        $this->_redirectReferer();
    }
}
```

Now Mageto will read this couponPostAction instead of core couponPostAction.

Comment: Thanks its working but when i apply i want to show message that coupon code is apply or not .... like it show on cart page how can i do that?

Comment: Welcome @MuhammadHamza. Currently it is showing message on cart page. Right ?

Comment: yes ... but not showing on checkout page where i add know

Comment: As in answer I mentioned We need a proper controller override. This form is submitted on `couponPostAction` at `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php`. If you look at code for this function, it is redirecting to cart page.

Comment: I will update my answer for redirecting to checkout page.

Comment: can you please help me to do that i cant know. I am beginner.

Comment: I am working on it, update my answer soon.

Comment: Hello @MuhammadHamza, See my Update in answer.if need further help, let me know.

Comment: Welcome @MuhammadHamza :)

Comment: Hi @pawan today i upload live my code but when i enter promo code it redirect to home page n show message there. Please help me how can i stay it on checkout page

Comment: when site is on http it work fine but when site is on https then it redirect to home page.